# Having problem to install avrdude on macOS Terminal

Tags: microcontroller, avr, avrdude

First of all, I have trouble installing avrdude via Homebrew because of some network problems. So I download it manually from [its website](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/avrdude/).

However, after I unarchive the `avrdude-7.0.tar.gz` file I just downloaded, I can find no `bin` directory there. It's unusual.

Then, I added its directory to my system `PATH` by `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myUserName/Developer/bin/avrdude-7.0/bin/`. But when I tried to use `avrdude` in Terminal after I restarted my computer, It says `zsh: command not found: avrdude`.

How can I make it works?

[screenshot of avrdude-7.0 directory downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n1Ye.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you downloaded the source archive of the tool, not the executable software.

Now you have two options:

1. Download the binary executable.
2. Compile the tool yourself. Make sure you understand how to do this.